# How to use rd_kafka_poll_set_consumer in librdkafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

What is the purpose of this api- rd_kafka_poll_set_consumer() ?
In the rdkafka.h file it says that once you redirect the rd_kafka_poll queue (rk->rep) to rd_kafka_consumer_poll's queue (rkcg->rkcg_q), and you are not supposed to call rd_kafka_poll after this.

Can someone elaborate on what happens to to which queue? Should producer be calling rd_kafka_consumer_poll to view produced messages?

Answer (score 3):

`rd_kafka_poll_set_consumer()` forwards the standard events typically served by `rd_kafka_poll()` (such as error_cb, stats_cb, etc) to the consumer queue served by `rd_kafka_consumer_poll()`.

This simplifies the application poll loop since it will be able to serve the standard callbacks as well as receive messages using just one call to `rd_kafka_consumer_poll()` instead of also having to call `rd_kafka_poll()`.

As the name implies this event queue re-routing is only of interest to the consumer, producer applications should still call `rd_kafka_poll()` to serve dr_cb's etc.